# How to alter JavaScript objects using string-like paths?

Tags: javascript

I would like to control values in an object using a string as the path to the value to change. For example, I have :

```
let object = { v: 12, o: { v: 15 }}
```

If I provide `path: 'object.v'` and `value: 16`, `object` becomes :

```
{ v: 16, o: { v: 15 }}
```

If I provide `path: 'object.o.v'` and `value: 8`, `object` becomes :

```
{ v: 16, o: { v: 8 }}
```

The path can also point to an object, for instance `'object.o'`.
If the path point to a non-existing variable, the function will create it and also create the parents, for instance `'object.o.o2.o3'`

Actually I know how I can do that using a for loop and just creating the structure and changing the value on the last crumb but I'd like to know if Javascript provides with simple function for doing that.

Or here is how I would implement that using for loop

```
let object = { v: 12, o: { v: 15 }}

function update (path, value) {

  const crumbs = path.split('.');
  let currentCrumb = object;

  let i;
  for (i = 1, count = crumbs.length; i < count - 1; ++i) {
    if (currentCrumb[crumbs[i]] === undefined) {
      currentCrumb[crumbs[i]] = {};
    }
    currentCrumb = currentCrumb[crumbs[i]];
  }

  currentCrumb[crumbs[i]] = value;
}

// usage
update('object.o.v', 51);
// object is now { v: 12, o: { v: 51 }}
```

Don't JavaScript provides some useful function to update objects using paths or something ? Or what would be your way of resolving that ?

Thanks

**UPDATE :**
Some tells me to use `eval`, the problem is the `value` can be an object as I said. So writing `eval(path + '=' + value)` is invalid, I could use `JSON.stringify(value)` when the value is an object but then the reference is lost, that means if `value` changes elsewhere, the eval'ed path is not affected by this change. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I think is better send object like param, then the second param will be the path, is more dynamic... `update(object, 'o.v', 51);`

Comment: @kip yes sure, I was just providing an example, it's not really the context I try to implement here

Comment: Use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function

Comment: @Ammar yeah, but check my update please.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the [lodash](https://lodash.com) library, they call this a "property path array".

```
> _ = require('lodash')
> object = { v: 12, o: { v: 15 }}
{ v: 12, o: { v: 15 } }
> _.at(object, ['o.v'])
[ 15 ]
> _.set(object, 'o.v', 16)
{ v: 12, o: { v: 16 } }
> _.set(object, 'o.o2.o3', 'foo')
{ v: 12, o: { v: 16, o2: { o3: 'foo' } } }
```

Comment: thanks but I think I will go with the chunk I provided, because I'm trying to build a custom element so I don't want to force the users to load extra libraries.